# Combine 2 Scenes / Volumetric Fog from BI to Cyles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, volumetrics

I have a complex scene rendered in cycles and now like to add some volumetric fog rendered in BI.

I have linked some objects from my cycles scene to a new BI scene and added a  cube with a volume material. Now the fog is in front and behind my linked objects.

Now I like to render the Volume Fog and combine it with my cycles scene. How can I block rendering the fog behind my objects from my cycles scene without rendering them self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after some tries i found a simple solution.

create a new BI-Material, set diffuse and spec to "0" enable transparency and change to mask and alpha to "0".

This works fine for me!